# Bug script para deletar todo o banco SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, script, cursor

Eu tenho o script abaixo para dropar TUDO do banco de dados, mas em um dos banco que eu tenho o processamento que precisa deste script acontece um bug, por algum motivo ele não consegue rodar na primeira vez que eu executo, mas na segunda roda sem nenhum impedimento. Segue script

```
DECLARE @ALT_TAB varchar(250)
DECLARE @COMANDO varchar(8000)


/***********  DROP CONSTRAINTS  ********************/
SET  @COMANDO = ''
DECLARE vendor_cursor CURSOR FOR
  SELECT ('ALTER TABLE ' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.[' + TABLE_NAME+ '] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + CONSTRAINT_NAME + '];') as ALT
  FROM information_schema.table_constraints
  WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' 

OPEN vendor_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM vendor_cursor INTO @ALT_TAB

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN
  IF ISNULL(@ALT_TAB, '') <> ''
  SET @COMANDO = @COMANDO + ISNULL(@ALT_TAB, '') + CHAR(13)

  FETCH NEXT FROM vendor_cursor INTO @ALT_TAB
 END

CLOSE vendor_cursor;
DEALLOCATE vendor_cursor;

EXEC(@COMANDO) 
/**********************************************************/




/***********  DROP TABLES  **********************/
SET  @COMANDO = ''
DECLARE tables_cursor CURSOR FOR
 SELECT 'DROP TABLE ' + TABLE_NAME + ';' 
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_NAME <> 'sysdiagrams'
 ORDER BY TABLE_NAME

OPEN tables_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cursor INTO @ALT_TAB

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN
  IF ISNULL(@ALT_TAB, '') <> ''
  SET @COMANDO = @COMANDO + ISNULL(@ALT_TAB, '') + CHAR(13)

  FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cursor INTO @ALT_TAB
 END

CLOSE tables_cursor;
DEALLOCATE tables_cursor;

EXEC(@COMANDO)
```

Os erros apresentados são:
 (Obs.: O NOME_TABELA é sempre o nome de uma tabela diferente)

```
Mensagem 105, Nível 15, Estado 1, Linha 1
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'CT_ENTIDADE_PRINCIPAL'.
Mensagem 102, Nível 15, Estado 1, Linha 1
Incorrect syntax near 'CT_ENTIDADE_PRINCIPAL'.
Mensagem 3726, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 1
Could not drop object 'NOME_TABELA' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
Mensagem 3726, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 1
Could not drop object 'NOME_TABELA' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
Mensagem 3726, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 1
Could not drop object 'NOME_TABELA' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
Mensagem 3726, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 1
Could not drop object 'NOME_TABELA' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
Mensagem 3726, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 1
Could not drop object 'NOME_TABELA' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
Mensagem 3726, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 1
Could not drop object 'NOME_TABELA' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
Mensagem 3726, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 1
Could not drop object 'NOME_TABELA' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
Mensagem 3726, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 1
Could not drop object 'NOME_TABELA' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
Mensagem 3726, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 1
Could not drop object 'NOME_TABELA' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
Mensagem 3726, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 1
Could not drop object 'NOME_TABELA' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
Mensagem 3726, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 1
Could not drop object 'NOME_TABELA' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
Mensagem 3726, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 1
Could not drop object 'NOME_TABELA' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
Mensagem 3726, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 1
Could not drop object 'NOME_TABELA' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
Mensagem 3726, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 1
Could not drop object 'NOME_TABELA' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
Mensagem 3726, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 1
Could not drop object 'NOME_TABELA' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
Mensagem 3726, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 1
Could not drop object 'NOME_TABELA' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
Mensagem 3726, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 1
Could not drop object 'NOME_TABELA' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
```

O que poderia estar acarretando nesse erro?
Por que somente neste banco de dados ocorre esse erro?
Por que se eu executar duas vezes o script ele funciona?

Obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: Pelo jeito é nome de algum objeto que está gerando o erro no string SQL a ser executada. Aqui rodou. Comenta a linha que dá o exec e substitua por select @COMANDO para saber o SQL gerado então cole no management studio para ver se tem erro de sintaxe.

Comment: Há! Descobri! A variável @COMANDO era varchar(8000), mas a quantidade de CONSTRAINT fazia o comando estourar esse tamanho, por causa disso a ultima linha ficava cortada. Aí se eu executasse a segunda vez ele terminava de deletar o resto das CT que faltavam e funcionava. Consegui ver isso fazendo o que tu falou de dar o SELECT no COMANDO. Alterei o COMANDO para varchar(MAX) e agora está tudo certo. Se quiser, compila isso que eu escrevi em uma resposta que eu te dou os créditos dela! Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Acho que você mesmo pode responder, o maior trabalho foi seu. Mas fico feliz em saber que ajudei. Não sei se isso seria correto de se fazer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variável `@COMANDO` era `varchar(8000)`, mas a quantidade de CONSTRAINT fazia o comando estourar esse tamanho, por causa disso a ultima linha ficava cortada. Aí se eu executasse a segunda vez ele terminava de deletar o resto das CT que faltavam e funcionava. Consegui ver isso fazendo um SELECT no `@COMANDO`. 
Se alterar o `@COMANDO` para `varchar(MAX)` passa a funcionar independente do tamanho do banco.

@Murilo que deu a ideia de como descobrir o problema.